# Angular 8 : set production environment for api base url

Tags: angular, api, development-environment

Working on angular 8 project and I want to set two environments configuration, one for dev and other for prod :

**dev**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api'
};
```

**prod**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseUrl: 'https://serverurl/api/api'
};
```

the problem here is when I run **npm run ng build --prod** and test after that a register route on my api it doesn't work, on the other side it works when I test with postman !

Comment: You have 2 `api` in here : `https://serverurl/api/api`

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: @AdritaSharma that's not the real problem, it works when test with any api test tools, because the folder name is api on the server and api prefix is api also,

Comment: @AdritaSharma I didn't get any error, a 200 response!! and I didn't find any row on my database :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the configuration option to build with the proper environment

```
ng build --prod --configuration=production
```

In your `angular.json` you should find something like this:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        ],
...
```